# Laravel not inserting in database

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problem with laravel app. I'm trying to insert some info in database, and it works fine, untill I have addded a new row 'ip_address'.
Ip address is defined as varchar(255) and everything is storing except address.
What could be the problem?
This is the code

```
public static function log(string $message, string $action, string $request)
    {
        return Log::create(['user_id' => Auth::id() , 'log_message' => $message, 'action' => $action, 'ip_address' => '212.91.176.38', 'log_type' => 'log', 'request' => $request]);
    }
```

Comment: did you add that field to the `$fillable` array on the model? since you are using mass assignment

Answer (score 2):

To create an entry using laravel model, you have two choices:

Mass assignement using `create()`, in wich case you need to define wich fields are safe to mass assign.

```php
public static function log(string $message, string $action, string $request)
{
    return Log::create(['user_id' => Auth::id() , 'log_message' => $message, 'action' => $action, 'ip_address' => '212.91.176.38', 'log_type' => 'log', 'request' => $request]);
}

// file Log.php
//...
Class Log extends Model
{
//...
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','log_message','action','ip_address','log_type', 'request'];
//...
}
```

OR

Create a new model instance

```php
public static function log(string $message, string $action, string $request)
{
    $log = new Log();
    $log->user_id = Auth::id();
    $log->log_message = $message;
    $log->action = $action;
    $log->ip_address = '212.91.176.38';
    $log->log_type = 'log';
    $log->request = $request;
    $log->save();

    return $log;
}
```

Comment: `insert` doesn't involve fillable since it is a query builder method

Comment: when called on a model instance it involves fillable because `update` is `fill(...)->save` , if called on a builder, it is a direct update though

Answer (score 1):

you should define fillable property on your model with all your fields :

```
 protected $fillable = ['user_id','log_message','action','ip_address','log_type'];
```

Comment: I think you added an extra `=` :)